# Set a <front> page for different languages?

Tags: i18n-l10n, 9

Is there a way to specify the front page per language of a Drupal 9 site? I am looking for an interface that allows this to be set by a user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow user input, it's not an easy task. I would do the following:

1. Create a custom form (not a configuration form), using the Form API, that allows the user to input the path to the front page. https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/form-api/introduction-to-form-api

   How you work this form to manage the language is up to you - you could either use the current interface language, or you could add an additional input for language on the form.
2. In the submit handler for the form, save the submitted values to the Drupal State, using the State API. The State API is environment-specific storage, it is not exported/imported with configuration between environments. https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/state-api/overview
3. Dynamically override the `system.site.page.front` configuration, using the value retrieved from the state for the current language. https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/configuration-override-system#s-providing-overrides-from-modules